# get data between two date columns

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, oracle

**Table:**

```
pmComm      validFrom   validTo
6.00        2011-11-01  2012-01-24
6.00        2012-01-09  2013-06-30
9.00        2012-01-25  2012-03-31
8.00        2012-04-01  2012-08-31
5.00        2013-07-01  2013-09-30
7.50        2013-10-01  2013-12-31
15.00       2014-01-01  2035-12-31
```

I have a table and when I am searching data between '2013-12-15' to 2031-05-15, I want the result like this:

**Result:**

```
pmComm      validFrom   validTo
7.50        2013-12-15  2013-12-31
15.00       2014-01-01  2031-05-15
```

what should be SQL query to get desire results between range data?

Comment: `I want to result like this` --->  `I need that code`  ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will output the lower date-range limit as `validFrom` when `validFrom` is not within the range but `validTo` is.

Similarly it will output the upper date-range limit as `validTo` when `validFrom` is within the range but `validTo` is not.

```
SELECT
  pmComm,

  CASE
    WHEN validFrom < '2013-12-15' THEN '2013-12-15'
    ELSE validFrom
  END AS validFrom,

  CASE
    WHEN validTo > '2031-05-15' THEN '2031-05-15'
    ELSE validTo
  END AS validTo


FROM Table


WHERE (validfrom BETWEEN '2013-12-15' AND '2031-05-15'
   OR  validto   BETWEEN '2013-12-15' AND '2031-05-15')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use between condition i believe, you can find more here. http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php

And query will probably look like this

```
SELECT pmComm, validFrom, validTo
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE (validFrom BETWEEN '2013-12-15' AND '2031-05-15') AND (validTo BETWEEN '2013-12-15' AND '2031-05-15');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve, but

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE validFrom >= '2013-12-15' AND validTo <= '2031-05-15'
```

might do the job.

Comment: actually i want to those records that
match both fields and also if matched in any one column then replace with searching data like data 2013-12-15' to 2031-05-15 matching between table records 
"7.50"   "2013-10-01"  "2013-12-31"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE validTo BETWEEN '2013-12-15' AND '2031-05-15'
```